# Use logged in user merge fields in visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, visualforce-template, merge-field

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case Report Type" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Account"

replyTo="">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
 <html>
 <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      TH {font-size: 11px; font-face: arial;background: #CCCCCC;
           border-width: 1;  text-align: center }
      TD  {font-size: 11px; font-face: verdana }
      TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
      TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
    </style>
    <font face="arial" size="2">
        <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
        <p>Below is a list of Assets related to the Case: {!relatedTo.Name} </p>
        <table border="0" >
            <tr >

                <th>Case Number</th>
                <th>Origin</th>
                <th>Owner Id</th>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">
            <tr>

                <td>{!cx.CaseNumber}</td>
                <td>{!cx.Origin}</td>
                <td>{!cx.OwnerId}</td>
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
         </table>
         Best Regards,

        {!relatedTo.Name}
         <p />
    </font>
</body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

In the Signature section of this template I want to get merge fields of logged in User instead of {!relatedTo.Name} . How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **[`$User`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_user.htm)** global variable:

```
Beest Regards,
{!$User.Name}
```